# Making tabs Dynamic/Interactive?

Tags: shiny

is there a way to make the tabs interactive/Dynamic. For example, in the below example, suppose if Mycars did not have any data, then "MTCARS" tabs should not be shown. Similarly for Iris as well?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
       tabsetPanel(
         tabPanel(
           "IRIS",DT::dataTableOutput('iris_table')
         ),
         tabPanel(
           "MTCARS",DT::dataTableOutput('mtcars_table')
         ) 
       )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
  
    output$iris_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(head(iris))
    )
    
    output$mtcars_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(head(mtcars))
    )
    
  }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- function(tabID){
  template <- c(
    "var $li = $('#tabset a[data-value=\"%s\"]').parent();",
    "var isShown = $li.css('display') !== 'none';",
    "var $pane = $('#tabset~div .tab-pane[data-value=\"%s\"]')",
    "if(isShown) {",
    "  $('#tabset a[data-value!=\"%s\"]:first').tab('show');",
    "  $li.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');",
    "  $pane.hide();",
    "} else {",
    "  $('#tabset a[data-value=\"%s\"]').tab('show');",
    "  $li.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');",
    "  $pane.show();",
    "}"
  )
  sprintf(paste0(template, collapse = "\n"), tabID, tabID, tabID, tabID)
}

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 5),
        actionButton("toggleBtn", "Hide/Show IRIS tab")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            "IRIS", DT::dataTableOutput('iris_table')
          ),
          tabPanel(
            "MTCARS", DT::dataTableOutput('mtcars_table')
          ),
          id = "tabset"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    output$iris_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(head(iris))
    )
    
    output$mtcars_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(head(mtcars))
    )
    
    observeEvent(input[["toggleBtn"]], {
      runjs(jsCode("IRIS"))
    })
    
  }
))
```

I have not tried with three tabs. I think the behavior is not nice if there are more than two tabs. Please tell me if you need an improvment.